# Finding a device that uses emoji in DHCP

Tags: windows, logging, windows-server-2016, ios

Good morning,

I tried searching for this already, but couldn't find much. Recently I ran into an issue where someone airdropped an inappropriate photo to another, and used a device name of only an emoji. According to DHCP, when I test with my device, using an emoji as the name, it just changes the name to iPad.domain.local. Is there anywhere, such as a log, that I can search by the unicode/ascii/html code/anything, to be able to find the device? When I have over 1,000 users, and most typically with 2 or more devices, it isn't a possibility to just pull them to the side and check every device name.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anywhere, such as a log, that I can search by the unicode/ascii/html code/anything, to be able to find the device?

Your DHCP Server should have logged all requests and issued adresses.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately it just comes back as iPad.*domain*.local, and while I still get a MAC address, sitting there with 800+ students who could have changed the device name wouldn't solve the issue, hence some way to find a unicode or something.

Comment: If you have the MAC, you can locate the device on your APs and pin them down - usually to room. More than a logical device name, the hardware's adress, the IP adress of the OS and the indirect location (through the MAC) will be impossible. But you can try to blacklist the MAC and look for "I suddenly don't have Internet " users ... or give them a route to a 'special' captive network.